# appium displays duplicate objects

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, ios-ui-automation

Appium inspector is showing deallocated objects.
So I am seeing x instances of the same object, out of which only 1 is actually correct & visible( while rest are dead).
Appium tends to find the first such element and fails on performing a function(click,sendkeys etc...) on the first instance(which is dead)

eg.

1. I have a TableView T.
2. I navigate to T
3. Navigate to some other page(so that at the backend the objects are set to nil/deallocated)
4. I navigate again to T.
5. I inspector I find 2 entries for T. (say, T1 which is now dead & a current instance T2)
6. My code fails on clicking the Tableview as it finds the dead object T1 first & tries clicking on it.

I am Using appium 1.2.0 & automating an app on Iphone 5s with IOS 7. I am using Java(Eclipse) on my Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because an old element is referencing on another object. I would recommend instead of storing elements in variables, create methods which would get an element dynamically. For example, you have `button1()` method which calls `driver.findElement(...)` method. This way, you always have dynamic elements.